# Navigation bar: "hide" title but keep it for the subsequent back button

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationcontroller

In my app I have two SwiftUI views, let's call them View1 and View2. View1 is started as a UIHostingController and has a "Go to View2" button which pushes View2 on the navigation controller of the mentioned UIHostingController (no SwiftUI Navigation Links etc).
View1 has to display the navigation bar because it has a custom "Exit" button in the toolbar. View2 should show "<Back" navigation bar button which leads to the View1.

Problem:

- If I set navigation bar title of the UIHostingController to "", then
  there will be no "<Back" but "<".
- If I set navigation bar title of    the UIHostingController to
  "Back", then after coming back View1 will show "Back" in the
  middle of the navigation bar.
- If I hide the navigation bar at first, then "Exit" button will not be
  shown.

So, to sum up, what I need is:
View1 shows navigation bar only with the "Exit" toolbar button, no title.
View2 shows only "<Back" navigation bar button

How can I achieve it ?

**Note: the whole navigation logic is done with UIKit. View1 notifies the view model which calls a delegate which pushes View2 on the navigation stack. There are no SwiftUI navigation links etc.**

Answer (score 1):

You might want consider a hidden Navigation Link so you get the push behaviour you are looking for. This will leave you with the following views;

```
struct View1: View {
    @State private var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Present") {
                    isActive = true
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: View2(), isActive: $isActive) {
                    EmptyView()
                }.hidden()
            }.toolbar(content: {
                Button("Exit") {
                    print("Exit view")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("View 2")
        }
    }
}
```

Your first view will use the button to present view 2 through a push animation. Giving you the back button behaviour you are looking for. Your first view will have no title and a exit button in the toolbar in the right top corner.

Comment: unfortunately the whole navigation logic including toolbar button is done through the UIHostingController and this has to be kept. No Navigation Links in swift UI allowed because this would mess up with an already existing navigation controller which might cause weird issues.

Comment: Okay, so you basically want to manipulate a UIKit navigationbar from within swiftUI. But I'm not sure if that approach is correct here. You are going to have to do a lot of custom work to keep the default iOS behaviour. I would add the exit button and it's logic to your SwiftUI view. Then you can present `view1` as a `UIHostedViewController` and keep the default navigationbar behaviour in SwiftUI. If that's not possible, could you provide me with a small example that replicates the problem?